# Exterior product between dual vectors in homogeneous coordinates

Tags: projective-geometry, geometric-algebras

In 3D-projective geometry the homogeneous coordinates of the line connecting two points with homogeneous coordinates $(x_0 : x_1 : x_2 : x_3)$ and $(y_0 : y_1 : y_2 : y_3)$ can be calculated as a kind of exterior product. With $\Delta_{ij} = x_iy_j-x_jx_i$ one gets the six Plücker coordinates of the line: $(\Delta_{01} : \Delta_{02} : \Delta_{03} : \Delta_{23} : \Delta_{31} : \Delta_{12})$.

Suppose now a plane has homogeneous coordinates  $(p_0 : p_1 : p_2 : p_3)$.
Does the same exterior product $\Delta_{ij} = x_ip_j-x_jp_i$ in this case have any geometrical or other meaning at all? It would be as if in geometric algebra one calculates the bivector of a vector and another vector of the dual space.

I only see that the plane is treated as if it is a point with the same coordinates, but surely there is no interpretation for the mapping $$\text{Plane}(p_0 : p_1 : p_2 : p_3) \mapsto  \text{Point}(p_0 : p_1 : p_2 : p_3)$$ is there?

I ask this because I noticed that in the definition of relativistic angular momentum in physics one defines a four-vector effectively in such a way.

Comment: In 2d I often think about reinterpreting points as lines as a special case of polarity or pole-polar relationship, namely the one where the matrix of the underlying quadric is the unit matrix, which represents a purely complex quadric with no real points on it. All of this should hold in 3d as well. I don't see this adding much value here, since the line connecting one point to the pole of some line or plane feels pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Agreed. It's just strange that it is done this way in physics.

Answer (score 0):

One can construct a correspondence between projective geometry and geometric algebra such that 1-blades correspond to points, 2-blades to lines, 3-blades to planes, and 4-blades to volumes. Since planes correspond to 3-blades, and you can't form an antisymmetric wedge product on two 3-blades, there's no meaningful result to find.

Furthermore, dualizing those 3-blades to 1-blades is not meaningful; you cannot use full duals in projective geometry, as that involves dualizing over the projective dimension--which is inherently non-metrical and thus does not have a concept of a natural correspondence between vectors and dual vectors. More succinctly, there is no unique point corresponding to a given affine plane. How could there be?

Angular momentum in physics can be defined as a grade-2 multivector--a plane or linear combination of planes--but that is where the correspondence ends.

Comment: 'no antisymmetric wedge product on two 3-blades': in 3-D proj. geom. one can of course calculate the meeting line of two planes with plücker coordinates which is anti-symmetric. 'Dualizing 3-blades to 1-blades' is in 3-D proj. geom. just a polarity w.r.t. a quadric. So I am not sure what you are saying?